# Auto Python code suggestion experience as DataCamp for Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Given the long title I'd like to start off with a small explanation.
First off, [DataCamp](https://datacamp.com/) is an platform where you can follow quick programming courses (such as Python) and interactively play with its exercises.

What I'm looking for is a similar typing experience in Jupyter Notebook (like DataCamp offers), where it real-time shows and refreshes the code suggestions as I'm typing, **but absolutely not autofill anything in my stead**.
*(So not like Hinterland, unless there's a way to disable Hinterland's autofill and only keep the real-time suggesiton drop-down list)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think many ides can do this. You can try to use [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). They have community edition and education edition for free.

Comment: Yeah, there may be many alternative IDEs that can do it, probably even Jupyter Lab for some of its extensions. But if possible I would like to have that feature in Jupyter Notebook.